# How to make PHP request GET asynchronous

Tags: php, asynchronous

**I want to make PHP request GET asynchronous**, but my version PHP is 5.2.13 and the version of curl is 7.16.4, that has many limits.

I tried:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
```

But it does not work. As I know, that just works from PHP 5.2.3

So I read the other solution fsockopen:

```
function curl_request_async($url, $params, $type='POST')
  {
      if (count($params)>0){
          $post_params = array();

          foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
            if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
            $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
          }
          $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);
      }

      $parts    =   parse_url($url);

      $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
          isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
          $errno, $errstr, 30);

      // Data goes in the path for a GET request
      if(('GET' == $type)&& isset($post_string)) $parts['path'] .= '?'.$post_string;

      $out = "$type ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
      $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
      $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
      $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
      $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
      // Data goes in the request body for a POST request
      if ('POST' == $type && isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;

      fwrite($fp, $out);
      fclose($fp);
  }
```

that works with POST but that does not work with GET. I want to make the request GET asynchronous

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you so much

Comment: How is this asynchronous?

Comment: What exactly isn't working, can you clarify what your issue is?

Comment: that's not asynchronous. You should use an external call (exec) with another php script file (or .sh, or other). Put it in background and manage the output with files. All depends why you want this call asynchronous.

Comment: How does this make sense - you request data (GET) but don't want to actually receive it?

Comment: i dont think problem in this function,are you sure  type argument is "get" when this is invoked?

Comment: Sorry all, I mean I want to put the request GET in background (I don't want to wait the response from the request GET and continue execute the rest PHP). I don't have PHP CLI in the server so I can't make exec 1 another php file

Comment: @mehdi nejati: Yep, I passed "GET" in the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to make a web request respond asynchronously?  HTTP requests are meant to be responded synchronously.

I would suggest that if you would like to decouple a long running request/process in the backend from the front end so the response is more snappy, would be to use a background PHP worker, over rabbitMQ or beanstalkd, and have that run your long running process in the background.  Your HTTP request would simply return a job ID, which you can use to make another call to check on the status of the long running job.  Additionally, when the job is done, you can have it make a call back to notify the caller that the job is done, so additional trigger or programming flow could be continued.

Comment: Sorry all, I mean I want to put the request GET in background (I don't want to wait the response from the request GET and continue execute the rest PHP). I don't have PHP CLI in the server so I can't make exec 1 another php file